# Cannot open Home folder via Finder directly

Tags: macos, finder, osx-mountain-lion

Home folder in my mac turns Cannot be opened by Finder directly to and:

1. have the creation and modification date: january 24th 1984, 09:00
2. are grayed out
3. have 0 item

but it still appeared to have their correct size.and "Go to folder" in Finder and "open" command in Terminal works well in getting access to this folder and there is no problem for finder to open all Subdirectories in Home Folder.

I'm on 10.8.2